# how to replace empty cell in UTF-8 CSV file with dummy data (data_row_number)

Tags: python, csv, vbscript

I have a UTF-8 CSV file with 200000 rows of data and need to replace the empty cells. Can a script can do it?  Thanks.

```
LE_NA,SH_NA,ID_NUM,OC_NA,OT_NA,OC_SURN,OTHER_NA,SURN,BIRTH_DATE,PID,ADD1,ADD2,ADD3,ADD
"王","王","A123456","王","","王","王","王","1980-10-6","","Hong Kong","香港","香港","香港"
"陳","陳","A123456","陳","","陳","陳","","1970-1-6","","Hong Kong","香港","香港","香港"
"李","李","A65456","李","","李","李","","1978-1-6","","Hong Kong","香港","香港","香港"
"方","方","A166456","方","","方","方","","1972-4-6","","Hong Kong","香港","香港","香港"
```

Comment: 1. First read file ( pandas or csv reader ) 2. Replace your target values. Try at your end, if you stuck let us know. If you have already tried, please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.x it could be done as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(line.replace('\0', '') for line in f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv_input):
        csv_output.writerow(v if len(v) else str(row_number) for v in row)
```

Giving you:

```
LE_NA,SH_NA,ID_NUM,OC_NA,OT_NA,OC_SURN,OTHER_NA,SURN,BIRTH_DATE,PID,ADD1,ADD2,ADD3,ADD
王,王,A123456,王,1,王,王,王,1980-10-6,1,Hong Kong,香港,香港,香港
陳,陳,A123456,陳,2,陳,陳,2,1970-1-6,2,Hong Kong,香港,香港,香港
李,李,A65456,李,3,李,李,3,1978-1-6,3,Hong Kong,香港,香港,香港
方,方,A166456,方,4,方,方,4,1972-4-6,4,Hong Kong,香港,香港,香港
```

As your input possibly contains NUL bytes, you will need to replace these before passing them to the CSV reader.

Comment: but there is another problem, the csv file with null value, it prompt an error and stopped before the line with Null value.

====================== RESTART: C:\Python37\convert.py ======================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\convert.py", line 7, in <module>
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv_input):
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
>>>

Comment: You need to remove them before passing them to the csv reader: e.g. `csv_input = csv.reader(line.replace('\0', '') for line in f_input)`